# Bluemix Visual recognition service working with curl command for custom classifiers but returning result for default classifer with node application

Tags: json, node.js, parameter-passing, ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I am trying for Visual Recognition service, trained with sample images and created custom classifier.
When testing with curl command  it working fine and returning result only for that classifier mentioned in params.json.
but same is not working with node application, it seems that it is neglecting params.json while processing.
params.json

```
{"classifier_ids": ["<classifierID>"] }
```

curl command which is working.

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@virt.jpg" -F "parameters=@params.json" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=<api_key>&version=2016-05-20"
```

Below is node application code which returns result for "default" classifier

```
var visual_recognition = new watson.VisualRecognitionV3({
  api_key: 'api_key',
  version_date: '2016-05-20'
});


var params = {
  images_file: fs.createReadStream('virt.jpg'),
  parameters: fs.readFileSync('params.json'),
};
```

Even i tried by 
 1. putting threshold 0.0 into params.json
 2. using JSON.stringify on parameters.

It is only returing resilt for default classifer.

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vishwas

Comment: after debugging with Debug mode:
  NODE_DEBUG='request' node index.js , I found that its not taking classifiers from file but using default classifier. below is part of request.parameters: 
      { value: '{"classifier_ids":["default"],"owners":["me","IBM"]}',
        options: [Object] } }

Comment: I'm not a node coder, but I believe params.json should be sent as a file, just like virt.jpg  The workaround below also works, I believe by encoding the `classifier_ids` as a query parameter, which the service also accepts.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by adding classifier id in params with images_file

```
var params = {images_file: fs.createReadStream('image.jpg'),classifier_ids:[ "classifier_id" ]};
```

seems documentation is misleading or there is another way to pass classifier ids.

Comment: I've reported this to the doc team - thanks for bringing it to our attention.